# Ajax Contact Form not including message when received

Tags: php, ajax, forms, email, post

I am receiving messages from my Ajax Contact Form, however they only include 'name, email and a blank message.

I don't know how to post the code here and what parts I require but any assistance will be very appreciated as I'm not that techy.

http://pastebin.com/NTudv7vN

Thank you!

Comment: You can find out how to post code here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting And, much more can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straighten up the reference to the `$comment` var

You set it here:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
```

Then start referring to it as `$comments` here:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}
```

Simply put, you changed the `$comment` var name halfway down your code leaving you with an empty reference.

Comment: Hi Jk,

Ah I see now, for some reason I overlooked that. So I'll change the $comments reference to $comment and it should work again?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Hi @jk. Ah I see now, for some reason I overlooked that. So I'll change the $comments reference to $comment and it should work again? Thanks heaps!

Comment: @TomHutchison just make sure to change all the references.